# jquery autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, oracle, jquery-autocomplete

This is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'name':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is my code:

```
[WebMethod]

public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string name)
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=Client;User ID=cli; Password=cli123");
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT CLIENT_NO FROM SC_CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_NO LIKE :SearchText+'%'", con);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SearchText", name);
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        result.Add(dr["CLIENT_NO"].ToString());

    }
    return result;
}
```

But this is give an error message like this "ORA-01722: invalid number". How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator in Oracle only works with numbers. So when Oracle parses `:SearchText+'%'` it treats both terms as numbers and performs the implicit conversion:

```
to_number(:SearchText) + to_number('%')
```

This will raise the `ORA-01722`. The correct operator for strings concatenation in Oracle is `||` (or the [`CONCAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions033.htm#SQLRF00619) function).

Furthermore, as [@axrwkr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2022859/axrwkr) pointed in a comment, you may run into further error if your column `client_no` is a `NUMBER` datatype and Oracle decides to convert the right-hand side of the `LIKE` operator to a number (I think the rule is that `LIKE` will convert both sides to `VARCHAR2`, but I'm not sure).

If `client_no` is a `NUMBER`, to make it clear to both the database and any future reader you could write:

```
SELECT CLIENT_NO FROM SC_CLIENT WHERE to_char(CLIENT_NO) LIKE :SearchText || '%'
```